# URL redirection with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirect

I have published a mvc4.0 website on below url,

> http://demo.mydomain.com

After successful login, it is redirected to Dashboard like this,

```
return RedirectToAction("DashBoard", "Account");
```

It means it should redirect to: `http://demo.mydomain.com/demo/Account/DashBoard`

But when I login it redirects to follwowing url:
`http://demo.mydomain.com/mydomain.com/demo/Account/DashBoard`

**Why is `'mydomain.com/demo/'` getting added in url?**

Function in RouteConfig.cs file is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
  routes.MapRoute( 
  name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );     
}
```

Comment: Please share your RouteConfig.cs file.

Comment: Founction of  RouteConfig.cs file is -

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to add a host name in IIS. You can add host name via editing site binding.

[image]

For me it's works fine.

Comment: please provide solution without changing to IIS